# How do i tell which repository/artifact on mvnrepository.com is more widely adopted? nimbus-jose-jwt vs jose4j

Tags: maven, jose4j, nimbus-jose-jwt

I am trying to figure out whether i should pick(based on the adoption):

-[nimbus-jose-jwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/9.21) - **Used By** 279 artifacts OR
-[jose4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.7.10) - **Used by** 655 artifacts

I found that jose4j 's author, Brian Campbell, is active, based on the [commits](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/commits/), it has the features that i need i.e support for `JWE` and it works well, but what i don't like is this:

[image]

So, are developers picking jose4j, is it a good choice(am i being paranoid?) or should i move to nimbus(the **Used By** artifacts is more for nimbus, does it mean it s more widely adopted?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that vulnerability is in Logback, which is a dependency that's only used in the unit tests (further down that page you screenshotted shows the different dependency categorizations).

I need get that updated, obviously, but it doesn't impact the library itslef.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/196/update-some-dependencies

Comment: Perfect Brian, thanks & cheers!

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.7.11 also